# Not sure how to specify a style from a copied HTML5, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been slowly pulling apart an HTML5 template and have copy pasted a parallax section below several times on the same page As I have copied this 3 times for the parallax effect I also have the same background image as defined in the main.css

```css
/* ==========================================================================
   Counter Section Style
   ========================================================================== */
.counters {
  background: url(../img/bg1.jpg) fixed;
  position: relative;
}
.counters .facts-item {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.counters .facts-item .icon {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.counters .facts-item .icon i {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #fff;
}
.counters .facts-item .fact-count h3 {
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.counters .facts-item .fact-count h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
```

```html
 <div class="counters section" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <div class="item-boxes wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
             <!-- <div class="icon">
                <i class="lnr lnr-pencil"></i>
              </div> -->
       <a class="nav-link" href="#video-area">
              <h4>SaaS Assurance</h4></a>
              <p></p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The problem I have is that even though I have copied them, I would still like them to be their own sections with different backgrounds and with my limited experience on Web Dev I am not sure how class `.counters` from CSS which is defining the image I want to change is being picked up by the code which says counter section

Thanks all

Comment: You have a number of issues with what you've pulled apart. Your HTML is missing multiple closing `div` tags, suggesting your copy/paste of the intended multiple parallax sections may be incorrect. Your CSS is likely also missing a multitude of required styles (and the last class rule isn't closed) to achieve the desired effect. With more details we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, *Classes* can be used **more** than **once**, so *if* you copy the parallax section three times, then there should be three parallax section with the same background as declared by **.counters** which is used by every of your parallax section.

To make sure that every of those 3 parallax section won't use the same background, try to use *ID* instead as ID's can be **only** used **once** and **must** have a *unique* name.

When an ID and classes is used **together**, the ID attributes should *override* any declarations made by any classes used in the element. In this case, you can give an ID that contain an individual background property for every of your parallax section ( something like **#parallax-section1**, 2, and more ), so **.counters's** background declaration will override.

Further reading :

1. [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) by MDN Web Docs.
2. [Override Class Declarations by Styling ID Attributes](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/override-class-declarations-by-styling-id-attributes) by FreeCodeCamp.

---

Note: When copy pasting an HTML element, make sure you do select from the starting bracket till the closing ones.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the responses. I found the issue that the class .counters was actually calling the image from class counters section from the code above, it must have just been ignoring the space and the section confused me :)